# Etymology of "catch a bosso"

Tags: etymology, idioms, slang

Reading [*Look to the Lady*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look_to_the_Lady), by Margery Allingham, I came across the apparent slang "catch a bosso," used by Lugg, the Cockney manservant, at the beginning of Chapter 6:

> As soon as I caught a bosso of 'im and 'is 'arem going up that street, I come up to see what the 'ell you was up to---sir.

The meaning seems clear enough---Lugg caught a glimpse of "'im and 'is 'arem"---but I'm wondering about the etymology.  Is this an instance of [Cockney rhyming slang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhyming_slang) and, if so, what is the origin?

I should add that *Look to the Lady* is set in the late 1920s or early 1930s, so this slang might be localized in both time and place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Green's *Dictionary of Slang* has *boss*, "a view, or sight, of", which he suggests is derived from *boss-eye*, a "squinting or injured eye, or person who has one".

This is said to be derived from *boss*, "to make a mess of, to spoil".

The sources quoted for this are all in the 1880's, with an example from 1926, which fits quite well with your book.

Answer (score -4):

I have heard the expression 'bosso' usually to mean an idiot, a buffoon.

> 1. bozo
>      An incompetent person, especially in new companies. Bozos have a net negative effect on morale and profits, and everyone knows it.
>      .
>
> I first heard this specific meaning of "bozo" during a talk to business students by one of Yahoo's founders.
>   .
>
> Q: "What's the most important thing to do in order to grow your company from 10 employees to 100 or 1000?" 
>   .
>
> A: "Get rid of the bozos. Seriously, fire them immediately."

http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bozo

Comment: You are right about *bozo*, but *bosso* is a different word.